# Ember server does not serve dummy app while creating an addon

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write an Ember component addon. After complete the template structure I think it would be nice to see the layout inside the dummy application as a sanity test.

Follow the instruction below,

> The Ember CLI uses a dummy app in tests/dummy for testing. In tests/dummy/app/templates/application.hbs you can put calls to both the helper and component. Then, with ember serve, you can navigate to localhost:4200 to ensure that everything is working as expected.

http://johnotander.com/ember/2014/12/14/creating-an-emberjs-addon-with-the-ember-cli/

I generate application route using code below,

```
ember g route application --dummy
```

However when I use `ember s` it seems run the addon's app folder instead of `tests/dummy`. What should I do?

**Update**

I have also try to start `ember s` inside dummy app seems no effect. It keep show me the `ember-welcome-screen` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple **DELETE** `ember-welcome-page` from `package.json` file and then run `npm install`.

The reason is that `ember-welcome-page` only get disabled when it can find custom route defined inside your app directory.